# Find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f(x^2+C)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, functional-equations

I posted this question last time but that thread got closed unfortunately because I couldn't write the problem aptly and up to the point of proper understanding.

> $4.8.3.$ Let $C>0$ be an arbitrary constant. Find all continuous
> functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x)=f(x^2+C),$
> for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

This question was tried hard by a full group of students but with fail. I request everyone here to try it out.
My ideas: After seeing this problem I was reminded of the famous problem of finding all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},  f(x^2) = f(x)$, which was easy. I tried the problem in the same and similar manner but eventually failed.

Comment: Instead of posting a new quesiton, the correct thing should have been to edit your older closed post to improve it. If you have enough closed or deleted posts, you may be prevented from posting new questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first consider the case $c \leq 1/4$; we shall show in this case
$f$ must be constant. The relation
$$
f(x) = f(x^2 + c) = f((-x)^2 + c) = f(-x)
$$
proves that $f$ is an even function. Let $r_1 \leq r_2$ be the roots of
$x^2 + c - x$, both of which are real. If $x > r_{2}$, define $x_{0} =
x$ and $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{x_{n} - c}$ for each positive integer $x$. By
induction on $n$, $r_{2} < x_{n+1} < x_{n}$ for all $n$, so the
sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ tends to a limit $L$ which is a root of $x^{2} +
c = x$ not less than $r_{2}$. Of course this means $L = r_{2}$.
Since $f(x) = f(x_{n})$ for all $n$ and $x_{n} \to r_{2}$, we
conclude $f(x) = f(r_{2})$, so $f$ is constant on $x \geq r_{2}$.

If $r_{1} < x < r_{2}$ and $x_{n}$ is defined as before, then by
induction, $x_{n} < x_{n+1} < r_{2}$. Note that the
sequence can be defined because $r_{1} > c$; the latter follows by
noting that the polynomial $x^{2} - x + c$ is positive at $x = c$ and
has its minimum at $1/2 > c$, so both roots are greater than $c$. In
any case, we deduce that $f(x)$ is also constant on $r_{1} \leq x \leq
r_{2}$.

Finally, suppose $x < r_{1}$. Now define $x_{0} = x, x_{n+1} =
x_{n}^{2} + c$. Given that $x_{n} < r_{1}$, we have $x_{n+1} >
x_{n}$. Thus if we had $x_{n} < r_{1}$ for all $n$, by the same argument as
in the first case we deduce $x_{n} \to r_{1}$ and so $f(x) =
f(r_{1})$. Actually, this doesn't happen; eventually we have $x_{n} >
r_{1}$, in which case $f(x) = f(x_{n}) = f(r_{1})$ by what we have
already shown. We conclude that $f$ is a constant function. (Thanks
to Marshall Buck for catching an inaccuracy in a previous version of
this solution.)

Now suppose $c > 1/4$. Then the sequence $x_n$ defined by $x_0 = 0$
and $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + c$ is strictly increasing and has no limit
point. Thus if we define $f$ on $[x_0, x_1]$ as any continuous
function with equal values on the endpoints, and extend the definition
from $[x_n, x_{n+1}]$ to $[x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}]$ by the relation $f(x) =
f(x^2 + c)$, and extend the definition further to $x < 0$ by the
relation $f(x) = f(-x)$, the resulting function has the desired
property. Moreover, any function with that property clearly has this form.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first part you did was exactly the way I was approaching

Comment: There are many such functional equation problems with the equation given as $f(x)=f(g(x))$ for all $x$. Then the natural approach is to look at the behaviour of the sequence $g(x),g(g(x)),\ldots,g^{\circ n}(x)\ldots$. For more details read the book    https://g.co/kgs/povr5Z

Comment: Thanks for this reference

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(-x)=f((-x)^2+C)=f(x^2+C)=f(x)$, one may as well restrict to  $\mathbb R^+=[0,\infty)$.

Let $T:x\mapsto x^2+C$. The topological dynamics of $T$ depends on the value of $C$, which determines the number of fixed points of $T$ in $\mathbb R^+$:    $T$ has zero, one, or two  fixed points, depending on whether $C>1/4$, $C=1/4$, or $C<1/4$.

Here is a sketch of an answer for the case $C>1/4$, when $T$ has *no* fixed points on $\mathbb R^+$.  Let $t_0=0$ and
define $t_n$ recursively by $t_{n+1}=T(t_n)$.  Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n=\infty$. The sequence of half-open intervals $I_1=[t_0,t_1),\ldots,I_n=[t_{n-1},t_n),\ldots$ form a partition of $\mathbb R^+$.   Let $g:[t_0,t_1]\to\mathbb R$ be any continuous function such that $g(t_0)=g(t_1)$.  Now let $f(x)=g(x)$ on $I_1$, let $f(x)=g(T(x))$ on $I_2$, and so on, so $f(x)=f(T(x))$ on each $I_n$.